# Spring boot and how to configure tlsAllowInvalidCertificate for MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, ssl

I have a spring application that I need to connect to a MongoDB. This connection uses TLS with a self-signed certificate.

I can connect to this database without any problem using Mongo3T with the SSL protocol without PEM file.

I can connect via mongo commandline:

mongo --tls --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates mongoDB://user:pass@host:443/dbname

Without issue.

However if I configure my yml file with
spring.data.mongodb.uri : mongodb://user:pass@host:443/dbname?tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true

It does not connect, and I get a CertificateException:No name matching hostname.

What am I doing wrong? Could it be that tlsAllowInvalidCertificates is not supported for this driver?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue ? I'm running into the same issue as you